# Create Sublists Based on Property in Python

Tags: python, list, comparison

I've got a list of toys, and each of those toys has a color associated with it.  Each toy is unique, but some of them may have the same color.  I want to group all of the toys by their color and put them into sublists.  So essentially, I want a list of all the toys grouped by color.

I've seen a few posts on how to do this with a Boolean or a finite number of values, but I want to be able to do it with any color, or rather, any string.

Comment: You should post your data structure code

Comment: @Navidad20 I thought about it, but its a class with a single field that is a `string` called color.  Do you really need a visualization for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

toys_color = defaultdict(list)
for toy in toys:
    toys_color[toy.color].append(toy)
list_toys_color = list(toys_color.items())
```

If you don't want the color with each group, use this line instead:

```
list_toys_color = list(toys_color.values())
```

Comment: This is very different from how I was thinking of doing it, but that works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
colors = set([toy.color for toy in toys])
groups = [ [toy for toy in toys if toy.color == color] for color in colors]
```

It should work for any type of color that once appeared for any toy. 
Less elegant but more scalable solution would be not to iterate over toys so many times:

```
colored = {}
for toy in toys:
    l = colored[toy.color]
    if len(l) == 0:
        l = []
    l.append(toy)
```

Comment: This looks like a really clean and simple solution.  Do you think this might have any issues with scaling?

Comment: This will definitely have issues with scaling as your are iterating over all the toys for each color

Comment: @Navidad20 is right, I've just edited to provide more efficient solution.